# Highcharts - How can I get the nearest point on click event

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this Highcharts diagram ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zr1d70qn/)) are two events. `mouseOver` and `click`

By moving the mouse horizontal over the diagram the tooltip and the `mouseOver` event snaps to the nearest point on the diagram. How can I get this point by `clicking` anywhere on the diagram?

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
             events: {
                 click: function() {
                    console.log( 'click', this.x, this.y );
                },
                mouseOver: function() {
                    console.log( 'mouseover', this.x, this.y );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case it doesn't even trigger the click event.

For that I need to add the click event to the main chart.

```
chart: {
    events: {
        click: function (event) {
            console.log( 'click', event.x, event.y );
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I get the nearest point so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the click event on the chart in this way:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      click: function() {
                console.log(this.hoverPoint)
      }
    }
  },
```

where hoverPoint is a kind of 'state' where hoverd point is attached.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a4qjx91o/